# How LSTM weight dimension depend on input dimension?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, lstm, dimensions

In detail can we multiply weight(w as a scalar value) to input that can be n dimension?

Answer (score 0):

If you through how LSTM works. weight is directly multiplied with input and previous sequence . details here [Understanding LSTM](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) therefore weight dimension should be same as input dimension. 
[image: LSTM in detail]